# Make own class able to be saved in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, arrays

I use this code to get the path of a not existing file in documents directory of my application

```
NSString *path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"restaurants.xml"];
```

getting this path:

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/50BC3507-39BA-4F7A-86BA-254AB9DA6184/Documents/restaurants.xml
```

My question: **How can I make my class being able to be saved in an array?**

function to get path:

```
- (NSString *)restaurantListPath {
    NSString *path = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"restaurants.xml"];
    return path;
}
```

function to write array:

```
- (void)writeRestaurantListToFile:(NSMutableArray *)restaurantList {
    [restaurantList writeToFile:[self restaurantListPath] atomically:YES];
}
```

function to load array:

```
- (NSMutableArray *)restaurantListOfFile {
    NSMutableArray *restaurantList = [NSMutableArray arrayWithContentsOfFile:[self restaurantListPath]];
    if (!restaurantList) {
        restaurantList = [NSMutableArray array];
    }
    return restaurantList;
}
```

I created an array containing 1 JFRestaurant item and saved it with the function above. Then I loaded it with the function above and the array was empty (initialized but with no content).

If there would be an error while writing the file or reading the file the array would be nil not empty. So I think that the content of the array is the problem.
May my class JFRestaurant cannot be wrote to file. I looked at a tutorial and saw, that I need to implement NSCoding protocol to make my class being able to be written to file and did that, but the array is still empty. I also tried with NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver, but then I get another error

```
2014-08-25 16:52:23.969 Restaurants[5577:934385] -[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170050860
2014-08-25 16:52:23.970 Restaurants[5577:934385] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x170050860'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x185866084 0x1954180e4 0x18586d094 0x185869e48 0x18576f08c 0x185741d98 0x18670c9e0 0x18676e170 0x10007d3a0 0x100077cdc 0x189eb39ec 0x189f510b8 0x189f50b0c 0x189f5082c 0x189f507ac 0x189e997a0 0x1897f22a4 0x1897ece90 0x1897ecd34 0x1897ec534 0x1897ec2b8 0x18a125b54 0x18a126a00 0x18a124b84 0x18d96c6ac 0x18581e360 0x18581d468 0x18581b668 0x185749664 0x189f07140 0x189f02164 0x10007b518 0x195a8ea08)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

---

JFRestaurant.h:

```
//
//  JFRestaurant.h
//  Restaurants
//
//  Created by Jonas Frey on 15.08.14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Jonas Frey. All rights reserved.
//

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import "JFUtils.h"
#import "JFItem.h"

@interface JFRestaurant : NSObject <NSCoding>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *name;
@property float score;

- (void)addItem:(JFItem *)item;
- (void)removeItem:(JFItem *)item;
- (void)removeItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (void)setItem:(JFItem *)item atIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (JFItem *)itemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index;
- (NSUInteger)indexOfItem:(JFItem *)item;
- (NSInteger)itemCount;
- (NSMutableArray *)fullItemArray;

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name;
- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name items:(NSMutableArray *)items;

@end
```

JFRestaurant.m

```
//
//  JFRestaurant.m
//  Restaurants
//
//  Created by Jonas Frey on 15.08.14.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Jonas Frey. All rights reserved.
//

#import "JFRestaurant.h"

@interface JFRestaurant ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *items;

- (float)scoreOfItems;

@end

@implementation JFRestaurant

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aDecoder {
    NSString *name = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:JFKeyRestaurantCoderName];
    NSMutableArray *items = [aDecoder decodeObjectForKey:JFKeyRestaurantCoderItems];
    return [self initWithName:name items:items];
}

- (void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder *)aCoder {
    [aCoder encodeObject:_name forKey:JFKeyRestaurantCoderName];
    [aCoder encodeObject:_items forKey:JFKeyRestaurantCoderItems];
}

- (id)init {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.name = @"Neues Restaurant";
        self.items = [[[JFUtils alloc] init] defaultItems];
        self.score = [self scoreOfItems];
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.name = name;
        self.items = [[[JFUtils alloc] init] defaultItems];
        self.score = [self scoreOfItems];
    }

    return self;
}

- (id)initWithName:(NSString *)name items:(NSMutableArray *)items {
    self = [super init];

    if (self) {
        self.name = name;
        self.items = items;
        self.score = [self scoreOfItems];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)addItem:(JFItem *)item {
    [self.items addObject:item];
    self.score = [self scoreOfItems];
}

- (void)removeItem:(JFItem *)item {
    [self.items removeObject:item];
    self.score = [self scoreOfItems];
}

- (void)removeItemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    [self.items removeObjectAtIndex:index];
    self.score = [self scoreOfItems];
}

- (void)setItem:(JFItem *)item atIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    [self.items setObject:item atIndexedSubscript:index];
    self.score = [self scoreOfItems];
}

- (JFItem *)itemAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    return [self.items objectAtIndex:index];
}

- (NSUInteger)indexOfItem:(JFItem *)item {
    return [self.items indexOfObject:item];
}

- (NSInteger)itemCount {
    return self.items.count;
}

- (NSMutableArray *)fullItemArray {
    return self.items;
}

- (float)scoreOfItems {
    float value = 0.0f;
    float totalPossible = 0.0f;
    for (JFItem *item in self.items) {
        value += (4 - (float)item.segmentIndex) * 25.0f;
        totalPossible += 100.0f;
    }
    return value / totalPossible * 100.0f;
}

@end
```

Thanks for your help
iComputerfreak

Comment: If you enable a breakpoint to catch Objective-C exceptions, you should be able to hone in on what line is causing this issue pretty quickly.

Comment: Not familiar with decoders, but looking at reason: '-[__NSCFArray objectForKey:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance, it would appear you're trying to obtain an object in an array using a key, rather than an index. If you want to store something using a string key, use a dictionary.

Comment: @Dan: I get the error while doing [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:[self restaurantListPath]].
Mike: I'm not doing anything like that. In my whole project, 'objectForKey' never occurs. Only in the initWithCoder: function.

Comment: `JFItem` must also implement `NSCoder` (assuming that items is an `NSArray` of `JFItem`

Comment: You are right. items is an `NSMutableArray` of `JFItem` but after implementing NSCoder in JFItem it still shows the same error with `NSKeyedArchiver` and `NSKeyedUnarchiver` and still an empty array with `writeToFile:atomically:` and `arrayWithContentsOfFile:`